# Stop cmd.exe or calc.exe process(Windows Process) by javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello guys how can we stop a cmd.exe or calc.exe windows process through a java script function? I am calling a javascript function on button click on a web page.

I tried the below code but it didn't work.

```
   function CloseClips() {

            var wmi = GetObject("WinMgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process");
            var procs = wmi.execquery("select * from Win32_process where Name='CLIPSDOS64.exe'");
            var enumProcs = new Enumerator(procs);
            for (; !enumProcs.atEnd(); enumProcs.moveNext()) {
                var p = enumProcs.item();
                p.Terminate();
            }                        
        }
```

I am Getting the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: GetObject is not defined
    at CloseClips

Comment: Define `not worked`.

Comment: If you are trying to run this from a webpage then `window.GetObject` does not exist.

Comment: Back up and think about this for a second.  Why would a browser allow JavaScript code loaded into a webpage to affect arbitrary host processes?  Doesn't that sound like an egregious security flaw?

Comment: How do you run this code? Ensure that JS host object is provided by WSH (Windows script host, `jscript.exe`) or Internet explorer 10 and below

See details on original documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389763(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I do not want that a website can close any process on my PC. And as far as i know this is therefor not possible.

Comment: @ThomasKleßen It's Windows Management Instrumentation. It uses JavaScript too, but with own host objects, sure. WMI was wide-used in before - node.js epoch in windows environment. Access rights in WMI is same for C#/C++ application, launched from current user

Comment: @VladislavIhost: Thx for sharing this information. Every day something new...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing connection to the ManagmentScope i.e before GetObject(...):

for your local machine (for remote you will have to use ConnectionOptions with user/pass):

```
ManagmentScope scope = new ManagmentScope("\\\\localhost\\root\\cimv2");
scope.connect();
```